# symfony using own templates -> selected from choicelist

Tags: symfony, templates, controller, twig

is there a possibility (while using a dynamic router) to select own templates for a controllers response?

I am thinking about building a controller which looks up in database for a template which has to be displayed.

for example, there will be a bunch of folders inside "web/templates/" like:
- folder1
- folder2
.....

Then, I would like to use the "folder1" as startingpoint and search inside this folder for index.html.twig and use it as template for the controllers response.

anyone have some ideas how I can tell the controller an absolut path to the template? For the reason, that there will be no bundle existing which can hold the templates, I will have to choose the template directly.

Actually i have no idea how to tell the controller ..... I think i will have to handle it like a static template, but without telling symfony anything about it using yml settings or config.... for the reason that it should be editable by normal users without access to parameters or config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of googling: https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle

Read some code. I think you'll find methods you need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry, that was really easy. I just dind't found it an thought active Themes has to be defined in config.yml

```
$activeTheme = $this->get('liip_theme.active_theme');
$activeTheme->setThemes(array($template));
$activeTheme->setName($template);
```

thats all. Thx for kicking me to the right place